# Is the direction of an electric field opposite to the direction of a current?

Tags: current

I consider electricity to be an observation of the property of electron mobility.

If electrons go the opposite way of the electric field, what is the connection between the electric field and an electric current in a simple planar circuit?

Comment: Do you now the microscopic form of Ohm's Law? \$\vec{J}=\sigma\vec{E}\$

Comment: No, what’s microscopic, like where are you going with this?

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on the Drude model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model) explains it nicely.

Comment: Microscopic means it gives the current in an infinitesimal volume element of a material, rather than for a macroscopic two-terminal device that we normally call a "resistor".

Comment: (sorry, should have said the current through an infinitesimal surface element, not volume element.)

Answer (score 2):

> I consider electricity to be an observation of the property of electron mobility.

This isn't a good way to state it.

If you get into solid state physics, you'll learn that the term [*electron mobility*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_mobility) is already used to mean something else. It's the property of a material that determines how readily its free electrons can move. It's one of the factors (along with the density of free carriers and the charge of the carriers) that determines the conductivity of the material.

You should also consider that electrical phenomena include electric fields generated by magnetic fields rather than by charge, propagating electromagnetic waves, etc.

> If electrons go the opposite way of the electric field, what is the connection between the electric field and an electric current in a simple planar circuit?

This is given by the microscopic form of Ohm's Law:

$$\vec{J}=\sigma\vec{E}$$

where \$\vec{J}\$ is the current density and \$\sigma\$ is the conductivity of the material.

As mentioned above, the conductivity (for a metal or n-type semiconductor) depends on the density of electrons, their mobility in the material, and their charge

$$\sigma = n_e \mu_e e$$

where \$n_e\$ is the electron density, \$\mu_e\$ is the electron mobility, and \$e\$ is the fundamental charge (the charge on each electron).

If you consider p-type semiconductor or ionic conductors you will have to consider conduction due to positively charged particles, not just electrons.

Answer (score 1):

Note that electric current isn't a flow of electrons.   Beginners might think differently, but the pros have to take a broader view.

In dirt, in salt solutions, and in electrocuted humans, electric current is a flow of two ion populations passing by each other in opposite directions (typically sodium and chloride,) with no electrons flowing. In battery acid and in acidic dirt, electric current is a flow of protons (mostly protons. Negative ion mobility is low compared to +H ion mobility.)  In spark plasmas and in liquid metals, electric current is mostly a flow of electrons, but positive gas ions also flow.  And finally, in *moving* metal conductors, positive metal ions and electrons both move, each contributing astronomical, but opposite, currents.

What then is electric current?   It's the sum of all charge-carrier motions.  It's a *differential* flow: negative carrier-flow subtracted from positive carrier-flow.  (Hence, when we move a metal wire, no gigantic currents result, even though we're creating an enormous electron-motion.)

A typical beginner-mistake is the belief that all currents are electron-flows.

This misconception produces an incorrect mental model of circuitry, tends to reinforce a semi-religious belief that proton-flow is blasphemy, and typically leads to incorrect statements on electronics forums.

So, during electric currents through salt water, we have no free electrons, just interpenetrating clouds of +Na and -Cl particles flowing in opposite directions ...so which is the "true" direction of those amperes?

Comment: +1. The number of questions on electron flow on the site suggests that this is taught very badly. Your answer should be a good reference (if I can find it again when I need it).

Comment: @Transistor I'm convinced it's the "game of telephone" where, over decades, beginners' textbooks become more and more corrupt.  Their authors don't read Maxwell etc.   Once they get the meaning of the word "electricity" wrong, their explanations become completely unhinged ...but their math is OK So, we do our eng. homework and run our simulations, but end up with little knowledge of simple EM principles:  Electricity flows slowly in a circle, with none being gained or lost."Electric current" is when electricity moves along (most books insist that electric current is a *kind* of electricity!)