# Voltage to current conversion

Tags: power-supply

In low voltage applications, it is assumed that both voltage & current carries information instead of energy.

- So how is it possible to transform the information carried in the form of Voltage to Current without altering it and vice versa?

I’ve heard there are are many voltage to current & current to voltage converters. My question is that Aren’t current & voltage relative to each other, with voltage comes current & in current we can have voltage? Both exist at the same time & without one another is impossible.

- if so then what do you mean by Voltage to current & current to voltage conversion?
- How is it possible to transform them from one form to another?

for eg: If one of the terminal of 1k resistor is connected to 5V source & another to Input pin of any IC let’s say then:

- What is the Voltage & current at the input pin of that IC?

Comment: You are really just asking for a nice, long Socratic dialog, I fear. But you might first start by asking yourself what the meaning of "voltage" is, without it being taken with respect to something or somewhere else. Everything is relative. Start there, see where your internal dialog takes you.

Comment: **information**, *noun*, data as processed, stored, or transmitted by a computer. "*In low voltage applications, it is assumed that both voltage & current carries information instead of energy.*" This may be true in some circumstances. In power supplies, for example, it is not. Voltage and current provide power / energy.

Comment: Unfortunately you have so many unhelpful (not necessarily wrong in the appropriate context, but unhelpful at the level you're working at) that one-way written answers are unlikely to address what you need. I think you need a dialogue with someone who knows what they're talking about.

Comment: the usual component used to convert voltage to current or vise-versa is the resistor.

Answer (score 1):

> In low voltage applications, it is assumed that both voltage & current
>   carries information instead of energy.

No, voltage and current always "carry" energy one way or the other.  Sometimes more, sometimes less, but in order to "carry" information they have to "carry" energy as well.  The amount of energy required is a function of the amount of information transferred
 and the characteristics, particularly noise level, of the channel.  This is basic information theory.

> So how is it possible to transform the information carried in the form
>   of Voltage to Current without altering it and vice versa?

A resistor would do this, but you may be thinking of a transconductance amplifier.  What is your goal in implementing this?

> for eg: If one of the terminal of 1k resistor is connected to 5V
>   source & another to Input pin of any IC let’s say then:
>
> What is the Voltage & current at the input pin of that IC?

That depends on the input impedance, bias, etc. of that IC.  In most cases, IC inputs (analog or digital) will be a relatively high impedance, so you'll see 5V at the IC input with very little current.  However, you should check the specs on the particular part you're using.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

voltage is the amount of force driving electrons, current is the flow rate of those electrons, resistance is the common factor that lets you convert between them,

if you have a voltage source, and feed it through a known resistance, you have a current that reflects the voltage,

If you have a current source, and feed it through a known resistance, you have a voltage that reflects that current.

How this is accomplished with conventional circuits:

for small currents with a trans-impedance amplifier, your feeding a current across a known resistor to cancel the input current, you end up with the voltage across that resistor that you can load in various ways without changing.

for voltages, something like a howland current source might be chosen, the op amp is trying to match the voltage across a resistor to the input voltage, and you end up with a
current that you can load in various ways without changing.

Now for your IC input example, this requires information on what the input of that IC actually is, If we take the example of an op amp input, generally it will have ~1E14 ohms input resistance, this forms a voltage divider with your 5V signal through the 1K resistor, the voltage is essentially 5V unless your 1K becomes a much bigger value, the input current is just that 5V over essentially 1E14 ohms, so almost 0 for most situations

When you get down to the scale of femto-amps, or pico-volts that is where things get muddy, as you start reaching quantisation limits, when your counting only a few thousand electrons per sample. however your example does not seem to imply that this is what your referring to.

Comment: I suggest that it is best not to bring electron flow into the subject. This causes a lot of confusion for beginners. See wbeaty's answer to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/454376/is-the-direction-of-an-electric-field-opposite-to-the-direction-of-a-current.

Comment: I was trying to be thorough with my answer, I left out many other things like there is no such thing as a noiseless converter, that offset voltages and bias currents exist, and all this means translating between them loose information about the original signal. as well as many other effects that show up at the low end. I figured poking at definitions of the units was fair game so long as I did not say which direction you measured things.

Comment: this is going to confuse the OP